# Guides to Writing Macros with Error Message

Tags: macros, errors

I'm trying to write `\newcommand` macros that will check the user's inputs to arguments and return an error message if an error (for example, value out of range) is found. Is there a good reference? Thanks

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific about where your issue is. _The LaTeX Companion_ and the 'class guide' (`texdoc clsguide`) both include details of for example `\PackageError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`source2e`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **14 Error handling**) describes techniques to write errors and warnings (and information) to the end user. Here are some references:

> These commands are intended for use by package and class writers, to give information
>   to authors. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> \PackageError{<package>}{<error>}{<help>}
> \PackageWarning{<package>}{<warning>}
> \PackageWarningNoLine{<package>}{<warning>}
> \PackageInfo{<package>}{<info>}
> ```
>
> and similarly for classes (use `\Class...` instead of `\Package...`). The `Error` commands print the `<error>` message, and present the interactive prompt; if the author types <kbd>h</kbd>, then the `<help>` information is displayed. The `Warning` commands produce a warning but do not present the interactive prompt. The `WarningNoLine` commands do the same, but don't print the input line number. The `Info` commands write the message to the `.log` file.
>
> Within the messages, the command `\MessageBreak` can be used to break a line,
>   `\protect` can be used to protect command names, and `\space` is a space, for
>   example:
>
> ```
> \newcommand{\foo}{FOO}
> \PackageWarning{ethel}{%
>   Your hovercraft is full of eels,\MessageBreak
>   and \protect\foo\space is \foo}
> ```
>
> produces:
>
> ```
> Package ethel warning: Your hovercraft is full of eels,
> (ethel)                and \foo is FOO on input line 54.
> ```

The above macros are specialized versions of more generic constructions:

- `\GenericInfo{<continuation>}{<info>}`
- `\GenericWarning{<continuation>}{<warning>}`
- `\GenericError{<continuation>}{<error>}{<further help>}{<help info>}`

Also, a rudimentary way of sending information to the console is to use `\typeout{...}`.